# How to enable/disable checkbox on CGridCtrl in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cgridctrl

I am using MFC Grid control 2.27 (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27) in my project. I would like to enable/disable checkbox on `CGridCtrl`. I'm not able to find the direct method to disable the check box. In fact, when I write the following line, it disables the grid cell on which checkbox is shown, while checkbox remains enabled.

```
m_Grid2.GetCell(row,col)->SetState(GVIS_READONLY);
```

Please suggest any way to disable/enable both checkbox and grid cell at runtime.

Comment: You have to ask the author ..

Comment: FYI, the `CGridCtrl` is now available on GitHub too: https://github.com/ChrisMaunder/GridCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add a second image list to the control. This image list would have disabled (greyed) versions of your images.

In `CGridCtrl` header you add:

```
void SetDisabledImageList(CImageList* pList) { m_pDisabledImageList = pList; }
CImageList* GetDisabledImageList() const { return m_pDisabledImageList; }
```

And add the variable, just after the existing `m_pImageList`:

```
CImageList* m_pDisabledImageList;
```

---

Now you need to prepare yourself a disabled version of your images and populate a `CImageList` (beyond the scope of this answer - just need a greyscale version of your image resource). Then, you simply pass that image list in using the new `SetDisabledImageList` method.

---

Finally, you modify the `CGridCellBase::Draw` method and massage the code like this:

```
CImageList *pImageListToUse = nullptr;
if (!pGrid->IsWindowEnabled())
    pImageListToUse = pGrid->GetDisabledImageList();

if(pImageListToUse == nullptr)
    pImageListToUse = pGrid->GetImageList();
```

So, whenever you set the cell as **read only**, as in your original code, it will render the icon using the disabled image list icons.

The above works OK for me.